# Hide DataPoints in chart control from WinRT XAML Toolkit

Tags: charts, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, silverlight-toolkit, winrt-xaml-toolkit

Is it possible to hide the data points in the chart control from the WinRT XAML Toolkit from CodePlex? I'm using a LineSeries and only want a line without the dots.

Comment: It should be the same approach as in Silverlight Toolkit since that is where we ported it from. You can probably change the template for the data points.

Comment: Yes, but how I have to change the style for the data points. This is the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. Though I am not yet sure why it makes my lines orange...

```
<charting:Chart
    x:Name="LineChart2"
    Title="Line Chart Without Data Points"
    Margin="70,0">
    <charting:LineSeries
        Title="Population"
        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
        IsSelectionEnabled="True">
        <charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
            <Style
                TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint">
                <Setter
                    Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="0" />
                <Setter
                    Property="IsTabStop"
                    Value="False" />
                <Setter
                    Property="Width"
                    Value="0" />
                <Setter
                    Property="Height"
                    Value="0" />
                <Setter
                    Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate
                            TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint">
                            <Grid
                                x:Name="Root"
                                Opacity="0" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
    </charting:LineSeries>
</charting:Chart>
```

Comment: Yeah! It's working great, but you are right the color of the line is acutally orange, but this is not a problem for me. But if I have only one point to display, I see nothing on the graph, because of hiding the points. Is it possible to change the Style, if I have only one point to display? Thanks.

Comment: Of course - you could either use a different template depending on your data or modify the code of the line series to enable your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

@Filip Skakun thanks for the very accurate answer, and about your issue regarding **Orange Lines** try adding this property and change the color to whatever color you want.

```
<Charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="Charting:LineDataPoint">

                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Charting:LineDataPoint">
                                            <Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="0" />
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
```

it happens mainly because Chart's are capable of displaying multiple data series on single chart. and for Series[0] the default color is set to Orange.